# Woocommerce 2 items in the cart = price x

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, cart

I would like to add conditional pricing to the woocommerce cart.

I have business card products priced at 65.00 for 250 and 85 for 500. I would like it so when a user adds two product items in the cart at the individual price of 65.00 the cart total is not 130 but rather a value I specify.

I know some of the woothemes plugins *could* do this but I don't want to pay as I know somewhere out there is a simple enough solution.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The "simple solution" is to use [Dynamic Pricing](http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/).

Comment: thanks for the link Helga, but I am afraid I don't have $129 for this plugin. Would love to but can't

Comment: Ok, well then you are going to need to spend time instead, because this isn't a site that just gives products away for free or does your work for you. Browse around SO for similar quesitons and please come back with a specific question/problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a **woocommerce coupon** in Wordpress that will discount the desired products(s)/cart total by a specific percentage amount.

You can set various "Usage Restriction" settings that will make the coupon only be applicable under certain circumstances (such as minimum spend, products, expiration date). Users can then be provided with a a coupon code to enter at the cart checkout.

This will be the easiest and fastest the solution that doesn't involve creating code for Dynamic Pricing.

The following link will help you to set up a Coupon:

[WooCommerce 101 Coupons](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/coupon-management/)

For more specific pricing needs you will have to create a function that hooks into the Woocommerce shopping cart in the functions.php file. The logic for the function should be something like this:

1. Get the cart contents.
2. Check that the number of items in the cart are equal to 2 (or more if you want).
3. if $cart_count == 2 then $cart_total - $x_amount.

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29054877/how-to-modify-cart-total-amount-with-filter-or-hook-woocommerce) will help you understand how to write a simple function to achieve this.

Best of luck! :)